# How can I stop special characters from messing up my code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code, that pre-populates a hidden drop down field, in gravity forms with Post titles. The posts are events. So if the event is fully registered, it returns a message on the page, that the event is full. All works great, unless a post (Even title) contains a special character like an ampersand, or an apostrophe. In those cases, It ALWAYS shows the event is full. I'm guessing I am using the wrong function to display the titles. I've tried to make adjustments but nothing is working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
/**Gravity Forms Auto Populate Events Choice Hidden Field**/
add_filter( 'gform_form_post_get_meta_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_form_post_get_meta_11', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_3', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_3', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_3', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_3', 'populate_posts' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if ( $field->type != 'product' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-posts' ) === false ) {
            continue;
        }

        // you can add additional parameters here to alter the posts that are retrieved
        // more info: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)
  $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&post_type=tribe_events' );

        $choices = array();
        $stock_quantity = get_field('max_tickets');
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title, 'limit' => $stock_quantity );
        }

        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $field->placeholder = 'Select a Post';
        $field->choices = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: will sanitize  help?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title

Comment: what confuses me here though, is that it then will name it lowercase and hyphenated too. i still need it to display to backend users correctly.

Comment: there are different kind of sanitizing - use which ever you want .. or go with php methods to str_replace  to replace any special chars   https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Special Characters From Uploaded Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830020/remove-special-characters-from-uploaded-files)

Comment: After trying this a ton of different ways, it actually wasnt this bit of code that was the issue. it was a line below where i was using get_the_title instead of $post ->post_title - to match the above code to the default value for that page. that swap fixed it.